# Two forms in one module

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I would like to modify two forms in one page. I generated a module with Doctrine. I have:

```
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->forward404Unless($news = Doctrine_Core::getTable('News')->find(array($request->getParameter('news_id'))), sprintf('Object news does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('news_id')));
    $this->form = new NewsForm($news);
  }
```

this works fine.

I added:

```
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
      {
        $this->forward404Unless($news = Doctrine_Core::getTable('News')->find(array($request->getParameter('news_id'))), sprintf('Object news does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('news_id')));
        $this->form = new NewsForm($news);
        $this->forward404Unless($other = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Other')->findByNewsId(array($request->getParameter('other_id'))), sprintf('Object other does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('other_id')));
        $this->form = new OtherForm($other);
      }
```

and I get this error:

```
 500 | Internal Server Error | sfException The "OtherForm" form only
 accepts a "Other" object.
```

I use `findByNewsId()`

This works ok - if I make foreach then I have these objects, but I can't show this in the Form.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds (roughly) like you're looking to edit multiple objects within a single form - so in your example, multiple "Other" items (your question is currently slightly unclear).  If so, you'll probably want to take a look at Symfony's embedded forms functionality - see [this tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms) for details.